# Are there elasticsearch and kibana oss docker images available?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

kibana and elasticsearch have 6.x docker images readily available.  [ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/_pulling_the_image.html)  i need a 5.x image.  it would be nice to use formal elastic.co images if available.

i tried `docker pull`ing a few tags without success.  also, `curl https://docker.elastic.co/v2/_catalog` gives rejects w/ UNAUTHORIZED.

any tips?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are pure OSS docker images of 6.0, but the 5.x images that have been published at elastic.co all include the X-Pack plugin.